# Is a convert considered a real Jew if not keeping kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, conversion-to-judaism

If a person converts to Judaism is he/she considered a real Jew if he/she doesn’t keep kosher?

I’m concerned because my mother converted properly and in accordance with Jewish law, but she never kept kosher.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note amongst others that personal questions are discouraged - you should really ask a rabbi who knows your mother and her conversion process. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: In general, the general acceptance of commandments at the time of conversion is what matters. Full observance is not a condition of "staying Jewish". See for instance [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92646/11501)

Comment: @msh210 I think this isn't a duplicate because it's asking if someone's conversion is valid if he/she never kept kosher

Comment: @ba I'm not seeing that. The question explicitly states that the conversion was "proper". The only question here is whether the person is Jewish.

Comment: @msh210 The question is whether the conversion can be ruled invalid if the person does not keep the mitzvos since this is in violation of the oath taken at the time of conversion. I do not think that it is a duplicate of the question that was referenced. That question involves someone who is definitely Jewish and might try to *convert* to another religion.

Comment: This should be closed as request for psak even if reopened.

Comment: The responses were all very vague, but thank you for your time.